# Java Reserve Keywords

Tags: java

Are `generic`, `cast`, and `threadsafe` reserved keywords in java?
I am aware of the 52 keywords in java but looking for the new reserved keyword list.

Comment: I think there are only 50 keywords currently in Java, see the list on the link in my answer..

Comment: Why would you think that `generic`, `cast` and `threadsafe` are keywords? They serve no purpose in the Java language.

Comment: Where did you get the words `generic`, `cast` and `threadsafe` from? Did you read about these somewhere, if yes, can you please provide a link?

Comment: *What* 'new keyword list'? You're assuming that there even is such a thing. Do you have any evidence?

Comment: Anyone care to update these references for java 7 and 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this link [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). It's the reserved keyword list for Java 6.

```
    abstract    continue  for           new            switch
    assert (c)  default   goto (a)      package        synchronized
    boolean     do        if            private        this
    break       double    implements    protected      throw
    byte        else      import        public         throws
    case        enum (d)  instanceof    return         transient
    catch       extends   int           short          try
    char        final     interface     static         void
    class       finally   long          strictfp (b)   volatile
    const (a)   float     native        super          while

    (a) not used
    (b) added in 1.2
    (c) added in 1.4
    (d) added in 5.0
```

So, no, neither of those three words you listed are in the reserved set.

This keyword list can also be found in the Java language specification in section 3.9.

Comment: It seems to be 1.4 specification not sure generics added in 1.5 or not

Comment: @Abhisek: this list is up-to-date. Java 5 introduced only `enum` and Java 6 introduced no new keywords.

Comment: @Abhisek Bose, Only the syntax was changed to support generics.

Comment: `null`, `false`, and `true` are not on this list since they are not reserved keywords (as defined in the Java spec) but are by most other definitions since they cannot be used as identifiers.

Answer (score 6):

Java keywords are listed in the [Java language spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#229308):

```
    Keyword: one of
            abstract    continue    for           new          switch
            assert      default     if            package      synchronized
            boolean     do          goto          private      this
            break       double      implements    protected    throw
            byte        else        import        public       throws
            case        enum        instanceof    return       transient
            catch       extends     int           short        try
            char        final       interface     static       void 
            class       finally     long          strictfp     volatile
            const       float       native        super        while
```

> The keywords `const` and `goto` are reserved, even though they are not
>   currently used. This may allow a Java
>   compiler to produce better error
>   messages if these C++ keywords
>   incorrectly appear in programs.
>
> While `true` and `false` might appear to be keywords, they are
>   technically Boolean literals.
>   Similarly, while `null` might appear
>   to be a keyword, it is technically the
>   null literal.

Comment: +1 for explanation of how true, false and null are not actually reserved keywords, but boolean and null literals respectively.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) `generic`, `cast`, `threadsafe` are **not** reserved Java keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Till date, There are only 50 keywords in java. Those are listed below

```
abstract        continue            for           new           switch
assert***       default         goto*             package   synchronized
boolean     do                  if            private   this
break       double          implements    protected throw
byte        else            import            public    throws
case        enum****            instanceof    return    transient
catch       extends         int           short         try
char        final           interface     static    void
class       finally         long              strictfp**    volatile
const*      float           native            super         while

*   not used
**  added in 1.2
*** added in 1.4
****    added in 5.0
```

The keywords `const` and `goto` are reserved, even though they are not currently used. `true`, `false`, and `null` might seem like keywords, but they are actually literals; you cannot use them as identifiers in your programs.

Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html